# vscode change font-family only for font ligatures

Tags: visual-studio-code

in vscode I am trying to change font family only for font ligatures to Fira Code. I can do it with custom css plugin, but the class for font ligatures (.mtk10) is shared. So if i change it, then it also changes font for if, else, this and other keywords. Is there any way to target only font ligatures?

This is my custom css style:

```
.mtk10 {
    font-family: Fira Code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend that at all. You can, however, edit your own font and add ligatures inside that. Check this tutorial on [how to create a font with ligatures](https://www.calligraphr.com/en/docs/tutorial3/).

> You can also check out this [October 2019 Release Notes - stylistic sets](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_font-feature-settings).

If you'd rather setup ligatures with Fira Code and use that font as well, then you can do that by the following set of instructions.

**Step #1**: [Install](https://www.calligraphr.com/en/docs/tutorial3/) Fira Code.

**Step #2**: Set the font in VSCode settings:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
```

**Step #3**: Restart/reload VSCode.

That's about it.